# WITHIN Keyword in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, median, percentile

I'm trying to find the Median in one of my queries.

I'm using the `PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5)` function in SQL Server 2012.

Firstly, wherever I look up for reference `WITHIN` in not represented as a keyword (not highlighted in BLUE Color), But when I'm writing my query it appears in BLUE color. Does that play any role in the execution of the query ?

Secondly, I'm executing the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    Unit,
    Median = PERCENTILE_CONT(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Value ASC) OVER (PARTITION BY Unit) 
INTO
    #UnitMedian 
FROM 
    #ResultList
```

Interestingly, it seems that there are no issues with the syntax but I'm seeing an error in the following lines of code in T-SQL.

Comment: `but I'm seeing an error in the following lines of code in T-SQL`. What error you get?

Comment: Hey, Please find the below error. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 116
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.